# Unit Testing and VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I am familiar with jUnit.
What unit testing framework is very popular for VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least these

- [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) - probably the newest and most modern of these four, it leverages a lot of experience from using previous frameworks to makes things simpler and more open.
- [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) - originally a port from JUnit
- [MBUnit](http://mbunit.com/)
- MSTest - Built-in in Visual Studio Professional (IIRC) and up

Comment: I would shy away from the built-in unit test framework that comes with VS 2008 (MSTest).  We've been using it on our project over the last 2 years and it's been painful (there is a background test discovery feature that causes the UI to lockup for periods of time occasionally and it adds significant time to every single recompile).

+1 to xUnit for me.

Answer (score 2):

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php), the .net cousin of jUnit.

Comment: do u like nUnit over the built in testing framework in VS2008?

Comment: @bmw0128 - any day. xUnit may be better but the builtin one is a pita imho.

Answer (score 1):

If you develop c++ apps with visual studio I can recommend [cppunit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page) for unit testing which is a direct port of junit.